# how to remove text and background color from text in tinymce editor?

Tags: css, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to add a button in toolbar or transparent color in tinyMce `forecolor` and `background color`.

So that user can remove his selected color from text.

How can i do that?

Please Help...

Comment: @NoobEditor - i am using tinymce 4.05, i have tried to change color in plugin file of textcolor plugin of Tinymce.. not worked.. any idea

Comment: do you have any code to show....??m not much of `tinymce` guy!!

Comment: Shail Paras, I had that problem too, look at my question, maybe it will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561691/

Answer (score 0):

From TinyMCE version: 3.5.11 (2014-05-08) at least, adding a button to remove the text foreground or background color seems pointless as this feature is already implemented in existing buttons:

1. select the colored text
2. **click the "A" button to remove the text color**, or the **"ab" button to remove its background color.**

One must admit however that it is not very intuitive.