# Remove background color and font color in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am improving TinyMCE editor and want to add buttons Default color in forecolor and backcolor. This is how I get selected text with random style of background colors:

```
outer = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().outerHTML;
```

For example, there could be something like this:

```
<p style="font-size: 18px;"> 
    sadasdasdsasdasda
    <span style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);" data-mce-style="background-color: #00ff00;">sdasdasda</span>
    <span style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" data-mce-style="background-color: #ff0000;">
        <span style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);">sdasd</span>
        asdasdasdas
    </span>
    dasdasd
</p>
```

I already tried `.each` in jQuery, but not worked. This is that actual code:

```
$(outer).each(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-color': 'transparent'});
});
```

I am not master in Javascript, neither in jQuery. What could I do to remove all `background-color` from `outer`?

Comment: You can use add and remove class in jquery. you have to store css property for particular classes

Comment: You mean, for example class: `.transparentText` which contains null colors and after click add class? That would works, but when user select other text and that old text will be in selected `new` text, will it works?

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this? (fiddle.tinymce.com)

Comment: I will try to 'clone' it, but I don't so. It is company project, this editor was edited a lot of times, now we need to integrate this, what I have as task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All to need is edit function in plugin (`plugins/textcolor/plugin.js`). Then result will be:

```
function onPanelClick(e) {
   var buttonCtrl = this.parent(), value;

   if ((value = e.target.getAttribute('data-mce-color'))) {
      buttonCtrl.hidePanel();
      buttonCtrl.color(value););
      if (value == 'transparent') {
         tinyMCE.execCommand("RemoveFormat");
      } else {
         editor.execCommand(buttonCtrl.settings.selectcmd, false, value);
      }
   }
}
```

After that, edit `tinymce.js` is required too. All to need is editor `removeformat`, for example:

```
removeformat: [
   {selector: 'span', styles: ['background-color'], remove: 'empty', split: true, expand: false, deep: true}
]
```

(**FOR OTHER USERS**) to add new color to panel, insert this code in function `renderColorPicker()`, recommended before loop:

```
function renderColorPicker() {
   ...

   html += '<tr>';
   html += (
      '<td colspan="' + cols + '">' +
         '<div id="' + ctrl._id + '-00" class="color-box"' +
         ' data-mce-color="transparent"' +
         ' role="option"' +
         ' tabIndex="-1"' +
         ' style="background-color: transparent"' +
         ' title="Default color">' +
         '<span>Default color</span></div>' +
      '</td>'
   );
   html += '</tr>';

   for (y = 0; y < rows; y++){
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$("*").each(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bT79r/10/)

**Edit**

```
 var a='<p style="font-size: 18px;">sadasdasdsasdasda<span style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);" data-mce-style="background-color: #00ff00;">sdasdasda</span><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);" data-mce-style="background-color: #ff0000;"><span style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);">sdasd</span>asdasdasdas</span>dasdasd</p>';
var outer=$(a);
outer.find("*").css('background-color','transparent');
$("div").append(outer);
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bT79r/28/)

Comment: But this will change every background color in whole document. I need to change background color only of selected text, what is stored in outer variable.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was at lunch. Now it seem to be better, I will try to apply it on my script. When it will works, I will accept your answer.

Comment: look at my own answer, I finally find out solution.